# How to show spline-functions (k=3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, spline

I have some data of x and y-coordinates where x-coordinate is increasing. I used a spline (k=3) to get a smooth curve of those points and plotted it. Now I would like to know the functions f(x) between those points but I don't know how to show or emit it so that I can use it later on.

This is the code I used:

```
import os, sys, re
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
spl = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y)
table_path = 'path/to/table.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(table_path)
xs = df['a/b']
ys = df['N']
plt.plot(xs, spl(ys))
```

Comment: What do you mean with "know the functions"? Didn't you define the functions? Do you use some library that automatically fit some splines to input data? Can you show some code and what exactly you try to archieve?

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code correctly indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You constructed the spline, now you can evaluate it, `spl(x)`, on any values of x.

```
>>> from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline as IUS
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(8)
>>> y = x**4
>>> spl = IUS(x, y)
>>> spl(7)
2401.0
>>> spl([x+0.5 for x in range(8)])
array([  6.84210526e-01,   4.81578947e+00,   3.90526316e+01,
         1.49973684e+02,   4.10052632e+02,   9.14815789e+02,
         1.78568421e+03,   3.15907895e+03])
```

**EDIT**: So the OP was about the functional form of the spline function itself. The answer is not very nice: the spline is in the B-spline basis, and you can get the knots and coefficients via

```
>>> spl.get_knots()
array([ 0.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  7.])
>>> spl.get_coeffs()
array([ -1.65247462e-16,   2.87719298e+00,  -9.75438596e+00,
         6.32982456e+01,   2.24298246e+02,   6.92578947e+02,
         1.48921053e+03,   2.40100000e+03])
```

To convert it into a polynomial form you can use `PPoly.from_spline` method, which accept a triplet of the spline order, knots and coefficients. It can be easier to use `splev/splrep` combo instead of the `UnivariateSpline` class --- it's functionally equivalent and you directly get (t, c, k) tuples and you do not need to worry about boundary knots.

Alternatively, you'll be able to use the `CubicSpline` class which works directly in the polynomial basis in the future scipy version (0.18+).

Comment: Sure, that's how i get the y-coordinates of all those points (which I already have in my table except for the interpolated ones). But what I'm looking for is the actual polynomial function which is used by the scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline let's say for the points 1 to 4 ?

Comment: OK, that's a different question then. Please see edit.

Comment: from_spline returns a PPoly object.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that myself now. When I try to let me show the polynomial function generated by PPoly.from_spline with .roots() then I get an array of 2 values. Hence I should get polynomial functions out of it considering that I had 24 points at the beginning. Any ideas how to get the polynomial functions in correct form?